# ifthen and etoolbox cause faulty index

Tags: conditionals, indexing, etoolbox

I am using the `ifthen` package to include/exclude passages in my document. However, I have noticed that when I have two formatted index entries for the same term, one inside `\ifthenelse` and one outside, then they are not combined in the index, although they should be.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx, ifthen}
\newboolean{include}
\setboolean{include}{true}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
foo\index{myterm@\textit{myterm}}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{include}}{%
bar\index{myterm@\textit{myterm}}%
}{}%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The resulting index has two separate lines for "myterm".

I also tried etoolbox instead of ifthen, but interestingly the same problem occurs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx, etoolbox}
\newtoggle{include}
\toggletrue{include}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
foo\index{myterm@\textit{myterm}}%
\iftoggle{include}{%
bar\index{myterm@\textit{myterm}}%
}{}%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I'm using pdflatex. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is already explained by Joseph Wright's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260491/16967), that the second `\index` call is inside the argument of another macro. Then the the index entry text is not read verbatim and macros are expanded. Due to LaTeX's protection mechanism, the robust macro `\textit` is expanded by `\protected@write` to `\protect\textit␣`. The space at the end is part of the macro name. `\protect` has the meaning `\noexpand\protect\noexpand`. Because of the `\noexpand`s, the expansion stops. During the output routine, `\protect` becomes `\noexpand` and the token `\textit␣` is written to the output file as `\textit␣␣`. The additional space comes from TeX, which puts a space after multi-letter command tokens.

The `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{myterm@\textit{myterm}}{1}
\indexentry{myterm@\textit  {myterm}}{1}
```

Makeindex knows option `-c` which compresses successive spaces to one space. Then entries with one or more spaces would be treated the same (e.g., `\textit␣` and `\textit␣␣` would be equal then). But this does not help with entries with and without space.

There is a manual workaround. `\string` prevents the expansion of the token by converting it to letters without appending a space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx, ifthen}
\newboolean{include}
\setboolean{include}{true}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
foo\index{myterm@\textit{myterm}}%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{include}}{%
  bar\index{myterm@\string\textit{myterm}}%
}{}%
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `.idx` file now is correct:

```
\indexentry{myterm@\textit{myterm}}{1}
\indexentry{myterm@\textit{myterm}}{1}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\index` command reads its argument in a verbatim-like manner. That means that it cannot be used inside the argument to other commands, at least not if you want it to continue to work correctly. If you look at the `.idx` file you have you'll find

```
\indexentry{myterm@\textit{myterm}}{1}
\indexentry{myterm@\textit  {myterm}}{1}
```

where the entry with the spaces is from your second use of `\index`. Note that this is not due to `ifthen` or `etoolbox`: *any* command absorbing an argument will cause the same issue.

Comment: At present I'm not quite sure what the wider context is here, but I wonder if you want something like the `comment` package.